# NSMutable Array from One Class to Another Class in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, nsmutablearray, xcode4.2

I have an NSMutable Array in FirstViewController class, I want to Pass that array to SecondViewController class. And I want to use that in SecondViewController class. I am doing this in Xcode 4.2.1 with ARC... How can I...? and what are the attributes i want to use when setting property... (OR) Explain me using Appdelegate files also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

1: Make a property for NSMutableArray in appdelegate, set the value for array in FirstViewController and retrieve value in SecondViewController.

2: Make a property for NSMutableArray in SecondViewController, and call this property for FirstViewController but making the object of SecondViewController, and calling the property via object reference of secondViewController from FirstViewController.

Comment: Thanku... will you please Explain Programmatically in Xcode 4.2.1... I have tried using the way u r explained...

Comment: sure, did you try 1 or 2 method?

Comment: I have tried so many ways... I have tried by sending message using a method with array as an argument.. Here I can Access Array But the scope of Array is in that Particular Method in SecondViewController.. Not Able to Access Through out the Class...

Comment: In SecondViewController header file, declare @property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *MyArray; then from FirstViewController , do this                     SecondViewController *NextViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
NextViewController.MyArray = thisClassarray;

Answer (score 0):

**in current class**

```
#import "SecondViewController"
```

---

```
 SecondViewController *NextViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

        NextViewController.nextClasssArray = thisClassarray;
```

**in second class .h**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *nextClasssArray;
```

**in second class .m**

```
@synthesize nextClasssArray;
```